# why is jQuery selector only selecting first hierarchy element on specific website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select some elements from this website: 
https://www.pexels.com/

For example I try this simple selector to match all the divs elements inside the div father container with "photos__column" class:

```
$('div.photos__column div')
```

But as a result it only selects the first  of all of them, why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML instead of a link to the site? That will make this more useful for future visitors since the HTML can change at any time on that site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$` could be anything.

Does this site have jQuery at all? You can check it in the browser console via

```js
$.fn.jquery
```

Querying with native DOM API

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div.photos__column div')
```

works.

Comment: To elaborate on this, if you're just using the Chrome console, `$` is an alias for `document.querySelector`, and `$$` is `document.querySelectorAll`. The former only selects one element. Indeed, that site doesn't seem to have jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

`$('div.photos__column div')` return an array with all elements with this pattern `"div.photos__column div"` but whene you call a function like `text()` , the function text use only the firest rsult of array

if you want to do an operation on all selected element , can you use  :

```
$('div.photos__column div').each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).attr("src") );
});
```

or if you want to select element by index , you can call element by hir index for example : `$('div.photos__column div')[2]`

can you use this query to get all img source from the home page :

```
var allimegs = document.querySelectorAll(".photo-item__img");
var newsrc = [] ;for(var i = 0;i<allimegs.length;i++){
    newsrc[i] = allimegs[i].getAttribute("src"); 
}
```